# How can you send SMS for an existing phone number without Twilio?

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio, chatbot

I want to make a service for existing business so if they receive a message it automatically gets parsed by my bot and if necessary bot responds to it from the same number.

With Twilio, you need to move your number over to them, which is very inconvenient for businesses who often have land phone lines.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to move numbers to Twilio in order to use the Twilio service because that is the only way that Twilio can receive calls and SMS messages from the phone network for that number.

If you are working on behalf of a business that has a landline, then why not purchase a Twilio mobile number for them that can be used for the chat bot? That way they keep their existing number for calls, but customers can interact with them in a new way via the mobile number and your chat bot.

Comment: because business won't like having multiple numbers that are associated with them, it'd create confusion whenever customer wants to talk to them. Forever, they would have to explain this is call number and this chatting number

Comment: Fair enough. With Twilio we need to have control of the number in order to receive the calls/messages. You could port the number to Twilio and then connect it on to a new business number that no-one else knows. That way the business will always have it's number, but it would be powered by Twilio too.